# How to show current loop iteration in click function, javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ox6gncL/1/)

```
var arr = [ [0], [1], [2], [3] ];
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    $('#btn-' + i).click(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });    
}
```

When I'm clicking on corresponding button console.log always shows me last iteration instead of the current iteration. Why?

Comment: Ditch it all and use this: $("[id^='btn-']").click(function(event){alert($(this).index());}); http://jsfiddle.net/m6Lbdpxm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a `closure`, In other words, create a scope per iteration. Now in your code all the event handlers are created in a single scope and the `i` inside of that scope would get updated instantly to 4. So as a result, when you clicking on all the buttons the result would be same. That is the updated one of `i`

```
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

    var j = function(x) {
      $('#btn-' + x).click(function() {
        console.log(x);
      });
    }

    j(i);    
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0ox6gncL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Because of closure! For that you can do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    (function(n) {
        $('#btn-' + i).click(function() {
            console.log(n);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ox6gncL/7/)

Comment: Your example does not work.